# PostgreSQL - proxying queries and logging them

Tags: sql, postgresql, proxy

Is there a way to log user queries in PostgreSQL, then store them as logfiles onto the server-side filesystem? (A proxy or something like that?)

PgBouncer doesn't log queries, tsung-recorder does log them, however the results are stored in the XML format (as opposed to simple text) abd without timestamps & user information. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jdbcspy](https://code.google.com/p/jdbcspy/) or [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/). They are both JDBC driver proxies. Advantage is that they work with any database.

Comment: I'm not a programmer unfortunately. I need a standalone proxy, not a driver :(

Comment: Then you will have to change the database configuration. Most likely you will need to set the 'debug_print_rewritten' (See documentation [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html]).

Answer (score 0):

You can log all statements on the server (either globally or for a specific user or database).  These will go into the pg log.  You can also log slow queries or the like.   This is an area where spending some time with the manual and getting some experience with GUC configuration and user/database configuration is helpful.

But per session you can simply:

```
set log_statement='all';
```

If you want to log to a separate log file, you will have more difficulty in doing that.